# how do I extract Name and Value from a line of text while reading from a file using Java?

Tags: java, file, parsing

A file name will be passed in from standard in. I want to open it, read it, and create some information based off the text in the file.

For example, if this is a line in the file:

`Hristo   3`

... then I want to create a `Member()` named Hristo with a value of 3. So I want to pull out a `String` for the name and an `int` for the value. The name and the value are separated by some unknown number of tabs and spaces which I need to ignore. Could I just read the line, use .trim() to get rid of whitespace, and the last character would be the value?

I have not shown the class Member() for simplicity's sake. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numMembers = 0;
    ArrayList<Member> veteranMembers = new ArrayList<Member>();

    File file = new File(args[0]);
    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader br;

    // attempt to open and read file
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;

        // read file
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // extract name and value from line
                ... ? ...

                // create member
                // initialize name and value
                Member member = new Member();
                veteranMembers.add(member);
        }
        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // Unable to find file.
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Unable to read line.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How would I parse that line of text?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the split function.
You can give it a regular expression as the argument
i.e.

```
line.split(" |\t");
```

will return array of the words ( {list[0] = Hristo, list[1] = 3} in your example)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Ahh great. I just looked into split right before you answered. The only problem here is the potential split into many elements. So it potentially won't be just 2 with the Name and the Value, but more with empty value. How would I overcome that... just check if " "?

Answer (score 2):

Use `split("\\s+")`, this regex ignore any space, tab, etc from the String.

Comment: I don't exactly understand how regex works... what is "\\s+" saying?

Comment: It says "ignore all spaces" from the string to split

Comment: Cool. Where did you get this from? Is there like a java package of regex expressions somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

A more robust way might be to use regular expressions; if you received malformed input (e.g., "Ted One"), parseInt() would throw a NumberFormatException.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

...

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*)\\s+(\\d+)$"); // Create a regex Pattern that only matches (text - white space - integer)
Matcher m = p.matcher(line); // Create a Matcher to test the input line
if(m.find()){
      // If there's a match, ..
    String name = m.group(1); // Set "name" to the first parenthesized group
    String value = m.group(2); // Set "value" to the second parenthesized group
}
else{
      // Bad Input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a home work. You came really close doing it. Use `StringTokenizer` to tokenize the `line`. Then create a new member object and and call setters for both the attributes with tokens as params. If your second attribute is an `int` use `parseInt` to convert and assign it.

Comment: Its not homework... its actually a Facebook puzzle I'm trying to tackle. Also, can you post some code... I've never used `StringTokenizer`.